# Increase heap to avoid Out of Memory Error in WEKA

Tags: heap-memory, weka

I am trying to run a classifier in WEKA, using a J48 classifier using the following command line:

```
$ java -Xmx2048m -cp /home/weka-3-7-9/weka.jar weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t input.arff -i -k -d J48-data.model &
```

Although the size of my arff is 43.8 M, and I aumented the heap space to 2048m,
I still received the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:132)
    at weka.core.Instances.initialize(Instances.java:196)
    at weka.core.Instances.<init>(Instances.java:177)
    at weka.classifiers.trees.j48.ClassifierSplitModel.split(ClassifierSplitModel.java:252)
    at weka.classifiers.trees.j48.ClassifierTree.buildTree(ClassifierTree.java:159)
    at weka.classifiers.trees.j48.C45PruneableClassifierTree.buildClassifier(C45PruneableClassifierTree.java:126)
    at weka.classifiers.trees.J48.buildClassifier(J48.java:249)
    at weka.classifiers.evaluation.Evaluation.evaluateModel(Evaluation.java:1485)
    at weka.classifiers.Evaluation.evaluateModel(Evaluation.java:649)
    at weka.classifiers.AbstractClassifier.runClassifier(AbstractClassifier.java:297)
    at weka.classifiers.trees.J48.main(J48.java:1062)
```

Does someone know if I am doing something incorrectly? Or can point me to a different solution to increase the heap?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quick instruction for the Ubuntu-Users: The heap can be set by changing the line `MEMORY="256m"` in the file `/usr/bin/weka` with your favored editor.

Answer (score 2):

**Weka's [instructions](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Java+Virtual+Machine)** state that the "-Xmx..." command will not work from the simple command line interface.  I believe you should increase the heap size by editing the RunWeka.ini file.  The link I provided should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

In terminal use this command

```
sudo gedit /usr/bin/weka
```

Change the size in the line

> MEMORY="256m"